# Inputs not binding to FormControls with the same FormControlName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Currently, I am facing an issue where the template is not binding to the formcontrols that share the name, removing conditional logic for sanity checks.

What I've tried: Spellchecking, different FormControl constructor calls, removing conditional logic for sanity checks.

TypeScript File:

```
  @Input() repairForm: FormGroup;
  .
  .
  .
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthorized = this.authService.isAuthorized;

    if(this.isAuthorized){
      this.repairForm.addControl('customerNumber', new FormControl('',))
      this.repairForm.addControl('originDate', new FormControl('',))
      this.repairForm.addControl('originTime', new FormControl('',))
      this.repairForm.addControl('originCity', new FormControl('Value Here',))
      this.repairForm.addControl('originState', new FormControl('',))
    }
    // other form code goes here
  }
```

Template File:

```
<form [formGroup]="repairForm">
  .
  .
  .
  <div *ngIf="isAuthorized ">
    <div class="form-row">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formContolName="customerNumber" placeholder="Customer Number">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formContolName="originCity" placeholder="Origin City">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formContolName="originState" placeholder="Origin State">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formContolName="originDate" placeholder="Origin Date" (dateChange)="logEvent()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formContolName="originTime" placeholder="Origin Time">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

On loading the form, the input associated with originCity does not display 'Value Here'. Changes to the inputs do not change the formControls they are supposed to be associated with. Additionally, the log event from the datepicker dateChange event logs the status of the repair form. After changing any of these fields, the form will be pristine and untouched. Finally, there are other fields created under similar circumstances which work.

Comment: Without seeing more context, the formGroup being annotated with @Input() looks odd. Is the formGroup passed from another component into the component in your example?

Comment: Yes the, formgroup is being passed in. Let me go ahead and get the code generating the form.

parentcomponent.ts
`  repairForms: FormGroup[] = [];



  addRepair(type: number){
    this.repairForm.push(this.fb.group({
      equipment: ['', Validators.required],
      equipmentNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      additionalEquipment: [''],
      additionalEquipmentNumber: [''],
      notes: [''],
      type: [type]
    }) as FormGroup)
  }

---
parentcomponent.html
  <app-new-repair [(repairForm)]="repair" ></app-new-repair>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, found the issue. Made a typo in 'formControlName' and only typed 'formContolName'